# How can i get the average of RGB values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to individually average the rgb values of each pixel in two images.

```
image = cv2.imread(images[z])
image2= cv2.imread(images[z+1])

height, width = image.shape[:2]

 for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
      (b, g, r) = image[y, x]
      (b2,g2,r2) = image2[y,x]

      print(b, b2, (b+b2)//2)

      image2[y,x] = ((b+b2)//2,(g+g2)//2,(r+r2)//2)

 cv2_imshow(image2)
```

```
print(b, b2, (b+b2)//2)
```

Some output:

```
128 137 4
127 136 3
127 137 4
126 135 2
126 134 2
127 132 1
127 132 1
```

When I checked the resulting pixels, I saw that some values greater than 128 were set to 0, and as a result the image quality of the output photo is distorted. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: "When I checked the resulting pixels" -- how did you do this?

Comment: @ScottHunter with print(b, b2, (b+b2)//2)

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the arrays? Note that they're numpy arrays so you can just do `avg = (image + image2) // 2` instead of the nested for loops

Comment: This is a common overflow issue. `r`, `g` and `b` are likely `np.uint8` type so `b+b2` can overflow (ie. be >255). THus, you need to convert the type to an `np.uint16`. Alternatively, you can use `r, g, b = int(r), int(g), int(b)` and the same for `b2,g2,r2`. Note that loops are very slow in CPython and vectorized calls should be preferred. For example: `image2 = (image.astype(np.uint16) + image2.astype(np.uint16)) // 2`